# Corporate logo added to openlayer web mab created with Qgis2web

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web

I have used the advice from a similar post:

```
<body>
  <h1>Megacorp Industries</h1>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
```

This works to put in a title at the top but it doesn't tell me how to float a corporate logo in the bottom right corner (for example) with some control over position and size.
It seems simple but I can't seem to find the answer.

I want to be able to stick the logo png in the "image" directory created by Qgis2web and insert it into my html from there.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: I have edited it as requested above.

Comment: Please edit your question and add code as text, not as image.

Comment: If I add that particular piece of code it interprets it and publishes the result into the window space.  It's 4 lines!  Is it that hard to figure?

Comment: It's not hard to figure, it's just policy of GIS SE site that any text info should be included as text, so it can be copy/pasted and is searchable.

Comment: Well like I said, when I clip that piece of code into to dialogue window it publishes the result not the code itself.

Comment: See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code how to insert code text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123796/discussion-between-mikeoramma-and-tomazicm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really GIS related problem, but purely HTML one. But anyway, first make positions inside `map` div relative, and then inside this div put absolutely positioned logo image. Image must have `z-index` attribute high enough to be above all OpenLayers elements.

Code could then look something like this:

```
<body>
  <h1>Megacorp Industries</h1>
    <div id="map" style="position: relative">
      <img src="image_path/logo.png" style="position: absolute; bottom: 25px; right: 5px; z-index: 10;">
    </div>
```